# References for generalized power of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

For a simple graph, the graph power is usually defined like this:

> The $k$*th power* of a simple graph $G=(V,E)$ is the graph $G^k$ whose vertex set is $V$, two distinct vertices being adjacent in $G^k$ if and only if their distance in $G$ is at most $k$.

([Graph Theory, Bondy & Murty, 2008](https://books.google.com/books?id=HuDFMwZOwcsC&pg=PA82), p.82)

It is not very difficult to extend this notion to directed multigraphs. But I couldn't find a reference for that, maybe you know one? For "power digraph" I got some Google results, "power multigraph" didn't help so far. My results:

- Bondy & Murty (2008, see above) only define the power for simple graphs and make no mention of variants
- [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphPower.html) is the same.
- In [Homomorphisms to powers of digraphs (2002)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X01000735) the power is defined for directed acyclic graphs without parallel arcs only
- In [On the heights of power digraphs modulo $n$ (2012)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10587-012-0028-3) the power is only defined for directed graphs
- In [Remarks on Hamiltonian properties of powers of digraphs (1994)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X94901074) the power is defined for directed graphs

A more general reference would be appreciated.